# how to show content as default in ajax

Tags: ajax

I have ajax code that when I choose AREA (first select box) I get all the cities in this area.

The issue is when I first enter the page - I want that the second select box (the cities select box) to be fill with the area default (the first choice)

This is what I already have:

**Client side:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#areaID').change(function(){
        var areaID=$('#areaID').val();
        $('#cityID').load('scripts/ajax/getCities.php?areaID=' + areaID);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>   

<form method="post" action="page.php">

    <select id="first" name="areaID">
      <option value="1">center</option>
      <option value="2">north</option>
      <option value="3">south</option>
    </select>

    <select id="cityID" name="cityID">  </select>


</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    function updateCitySelectBox() {
        var areaID = $('#areaID').val();
        $('#cityID').load('scripts/ajax/getCities.php?areaID=' + areaID);

        return false;
    }

    updateCitySelectBox();
    $('#areaID').change(updateCitySelectBox);
});
```